# Google App Engine SDK is open source. Would anyone from the cloud try to catch it to break the vendor lockin?

Tags: cloud-computing, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

Would it be possible/feasible/desirable that any "cloud" provider grab the source code of the [Google App Engine SDK](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/) in order to break the "vendor lock in" it imposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think it has been done, but I have not followed up on it in a while.  Good link to start with: [WAXY](http://waxy.org/2008/04/exclusive_google_app_engine_ported_to_amazons_ec2/)